# Как парсить с помощью retrofit вложенный массив?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

Есть json, у него есть вложенный массив `payments`, как его парсить с помощью `retrofit`?

```
"credits": [

  {

    "name": "Кредит Выгодный",

    "contractNumber": 4666888,

    "openedDate": "2018-02-09T21:58:57+00:00",

    "nextPaymentDate": "2018-05-11T05:58:57+00:00",

    "nextPaymentAmount": 8900,

    "percent": 15.4,

    "amount": 125000,

    "currency": "rur",

    "status":"active",

    "payments": [

      {

        "paymentDate": "2018-03-09T21:58:57+00:00",

        "paymentAmount": 3400,

        "status": "paid"

      },

      {

        "paymentDate": "2018-04-09T21:58:57+00:00",

        "paymentAmount": 3700,

        "status": "paid"

      },

      {

        "paymentDate": "2018-05-09T21:58:57+00:00",

        "paymentAmount": 4400,

        "status": "skipped"

      },

      {

        "paymentDate": "2018-06-09T21:58:57+00:00",

        "paymentAmount": 4400,

        "status": "future"

      }

    ]

  },
```

Для `credits` создаю `class Credits { //данные (id, name, и т.д.)}`, если создам тоже самое и для `payments`, то просто `null` или выходит ошибка

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Expected BEGIN OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 4 column 14 path $.result

public abstract class BaseProducts {

@NonNull
@SerializedName("name")
private String name;
@NonNull
@SerializedName("openedDate")
private Date openedDate;
@SerializedName("amount")
private Double amount;
@NonNull
@SerializedName("currency")
private String currency;
@Nullable
@SerializedName("status")
private String status;

public class Credits extends BaseProducts {

@SerializedName("contractNumber")
private Long contractNumber;
@NonNull
@SerializedName("nextPaymentDate")
private Date nextPaymentDate;
@SerializedName("nextPaymentAmount")
private Double nextPaymentAmount;
@NonNull
@SerializedName("percent")
private Double percent;
}

public class Payments extends BaseProducts {

@NonNull
@SerializedName("paymentDate")
private Date paymentDate;
@SerializedName("paymentAmount")
private Double paymentAmount;
}

public class ApiResponse<T> {

@SerializedName("resultCode")
private int resultCode;
@SerializedName("error")
private String error;
@SerializedName("result")
private T result;
}

public class ProductResponse {
@SerializedName("credits")
private List<Credits> credits = null;
@SerializedName("payments")
private List<Payments> payments = null;
}

public interface BankApi {
@GET(EnumsUrl.URL_PRODUCTS)
Single<ApiResponse<ProductResponse>> getProductsSingle();
}
```

Comment: Покажите полные модели

Comment: @RomanK. Добавил

Comment: так у вас модели вообще не соответствуют json'у

Comment: Они наследуются от BaseProducts, часть находится там, смотрите лучше

Comment: так тут нету BaseProducts, а я просил полные модели

Comment: @RomanK. Добавил

Comment: Ну так вы сообразили?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно просто перенести List из класса ProductResponse в класс Credits (т.е. привести модели в соответствие со структурой самого JSON'а)

Класс ProductResponse:

```
public class ProductResponse {
    @SerializedName("credits")
    private List<Credits> credits = null;
}
```

Класс Credits:

```
public class Credits extends BaseProducts {

    @SerializedName("contractNumber")
    private Long contractNumber;
    @NonNull
    @SerializedName("nextPaymentDate")
    private Date nextPaymentDate;
    @SerializedName("nextPaymentAmount")
    private Double nextPaymentAmount;
    @NonNull
    @SerializedName("percent")
    private Double percent;
    @SerializedName("payments")
    private List<Payments> payments = null;
}
```

А вообще, для POJO лучше не использовать наследование

Answer (score 1):

В общем нужно использовать [JsonPojo](http://jsonschema2pojo.org) он построит правильную структуру

Comment: Не то что бы панацея, но значительно упрощает жизнь. Хотя всё-таки надо понимать, что делаешь - в сложных, запутаных json's придётся таки разгребать ручками даже после POJO-генераторов

Comment: Согласен, но когда есть недопонимания, он помог...

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно сделать нормальный POJO с помощью генератора, потом , возможно править его ручками.
Далее просто указать с аннотацией то что вам нужно вытянуть.
Что бы добраться до вложенного массива `payments` вам нужно сделать вложенный класс в `"credits"`

Собственно [ВОТ](http://www.cyberforum.ru/android-dev/thread2274600.html)
 такой же вопрос с такой же проблемой. ПО сути ничего сложного.

Comment: Зачем дублировать, то что я уже написал?