# Выдает java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 4 column 14 path $.result

Tags: android, json, retrofit

Ошибка на

```
{
"resultCode": 200,
"error": "",
"result": [
{
"id": 1000,
"category": "Терминал",
"image": "https://loremflickr.com/200/200/logo?lock=1166",
"address": "433 Pierrepont Place, Henrietta, Wisconsin, 1587",
"location": {
  "latitude": "56.825212",
  "longitude": "53.232379"
},
"description": "Nulla amet dolor sint veniam elit."
},

public class Places{
    @SerializedName("id")
    private int id;
    @NonNull
    @SerializedName("category")
    private String category;
    @NonNull
    @SerializedName("image")
    private String image;
    @NonNull
    @SerializedName("address")
    private String address;
    @NonNull
    @SerializedName("description")
    private String description;
    @SerializedName("location")
    List<Location> locations = null;

public class Location{
    @SerializedName("latitude")
    private double latitude;
    @SerializedName("longitude")
    private double longitude;

public class MapResponse {
    @SerializedName("places")
    private List<Places> places = null;

public class ApiResponse<T> {
    @SerializedName("resultCode")
    private int resultCode;
    @SerializedName("error")
    private String error;
    @SerializedName("result")
    private T result;

@GET(EnumsUrl.URL_MAP)
Observable<ApiResponse<MapResponse>> getMaps();
```

Comment: Ответ в моем же посте, проблема решилась, ответ по [адресу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/863912/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-retrofit-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас неправильный тип. В JSON объект, а в классе у переменной - массив объектов:

> ```
> "location": {
>   "latitude": "56.825212",
>   "longitude": "53.232379"
> }
> @SerializedName("location")
> List<Location> locations = null;
> ```

должно быть так:

```
@SerializedName("location")
Location locations = null;
```

Comment: Уже решил, в комментарии написал, и там еще вторая проблема была с response